# dataGridView1_CellContentClick randomly doesn't fire

Tags: c#, events, datagridview

This is just bizarre. It's almost as if there are certain cells in the grid that are turned off. The whole thing was generated using "drag & drop", e.g. the grid is bound to a datasource and it works almost all the time.

I can click around time after time and it works perfectly but there are cells in the grid that don't fire the event. It is completely repeatable, the dataset is fixed.

What could possibly cause this behavior? No exceptions are being thrown, debugger is set to break on all...

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I've posted an answer which is really just a best guess - can't think of anything else causing this behaviour, but if the answer is wrong update your question (you don't have the reputation to comment I believe) with some code showing how you reproduce the issue - if it is completely repeatable then you should be able to give a good repro. As it stands the question is to open to be sure what you issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [CellContentClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick.aspx) event is only fired when the contents (the hosted control) of the cell is clicked. This means that the white space around the control does not cause the event to fire.

This is most obvious with a CheckBox cell - the only thing that fires the event is clicking on the CheckBox - however it occurs for all cell types. With a TextBoxColumn for example the event only fires when the text is clicked on.

If you want to know when anywhere in the cell is clicked, use the [CellClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick.aspx) or possibly [CellMouseDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellmousedown.aspx) events instead.

The `CellContextClick` event is generally for columns like the checkbox, button or link, where the mouse interaction with the actual content, not the whitespace, is what you are after.

Comment: It's just a text field, the whole grid is just text, nothing else. It works time after time, I get an event for every other cell. What am I going to post, the click handler code? Your response is appreciated, but provides no insight into this problem.

Comment: I will try CellClick. Maybe I'm foolish to think that CellContentClick is reliable. It's not an empty cell. Thanks.

Comment: @user1210111 But are you clicking on the actual text or on the whitespace that surrounds it? If for example you have a text field that is 30 pixels wide but your cell is 35 pixels there will be five pixels where the event is not raised. The cell context click event is reliable - it is isn't working then you have done something to break it.

Comment: @user1210111 when you say "it's not an empty cell" I'm not sure what difference you think this would make? The behaviour of CellContentClick has nothing to do with empty cells or not, but with the size of the control embedded within the cell - there this control is smaller than the total size of the cell you will not get a content click when you click on some parts of the cell.

Comment: David, the cell contains a string, the size of the cell is the same as all the others, in this case it contains two characters. You are suggesting that if I click on the white space in the cell rather than the characters in it, the contents of the cell are not relevant. Really? Thank you again for your replies.

Comment: David, you are correct. If I click directly on the text it works. So I guess I need to use CellClick rather than CellContentClick. This is my first time using a DataGridView, so please pardon my ignorance.

Comment: @user1210111 no problems - this behaviour catchs lots of people, so not an issue of ignorance! Please mark this as the answer to your problem and upvote it, it gives you a little reputation as well as giving me some.

Comment: I tried to upvote, I cannot without a reputation of 15. How do I mark it as anwered?

Comment: There should be a little tick beside my answer. Click and that and it will go green :)